# Mechanical Turk - can't view HIT, appears blank

Tags: mechanicalturk, categorization

I m trying to setup a few image categorization tasks on Mechanical Turk sandbox developer version. When I try to view the HIT(the annotation image), it appears blank. I clicked on the 'Accept HIT' button but I still couldn't see anything.

In order to make sure that nothing was wrong with my project setup in particular, I signed in as a worker to accept HITS on other projects involving image categorization. I still continue to see a blank image in their categorization projects, where the image to be annotated is supposed to be displayed.

Can anyone help with this problem?Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved - it was a simple browser incompatibility problem.

Comment: Could you please let me know what the problem was exactly? I'm currently developing a HIT with MTurk and I can only see it in the sandbox with Internet Explorer (Chrome and Firefox do not work, it appears blank as you have described). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know you have already answered this for yourself, however for other requesters out there I think this may be useful.

I was developing HITs and I too was having issues view the HIT in Sandbox in Chrome and Firefox, I realized that it had something to do with the script being blocked by the browser and the way to fix this was to "unblock the content" - usually a shield icon in the URL bar.

When further developing my HIT I added information about how to see the HIT in the description box of the HIT so turkers could read the instructions and then work on the HIT - to be absolutely clear to the turkers, I added a "(READ DESCRIPTION)" in the title so turkers would know where to look.

Hope this helps!