# Why does the MTurk sandbox only display my HITs in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am developing a Mechanical Turk HIT as an external question. My external question's webpage is hosted on Amazon EC2 and I am able to access it through Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer. I successfully launch the HITs containing the external question through Boto. I then sign in to the MTurk sandbox and accept my own HIT. However, it only displays when I am using Internet Explorer! Both Chrome and Firefox display a blank rectangle.

This problem persists if I change my webpage from a Java applet to a simple Javascript page.

Has anyone else experienced this? The following question is similar but the answer doesn't explain what's going on:
[Mechanical Turk - can't view HIT, appears blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368980/mechanical-turk-cant-view-hit-appears-blank)

EDIT:

This is actually true of ALL sandbox HITs I attempt to work on, not just ones I've created: only Internet Explorer is able to view them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of the new "mixed content blocking" enabled in some browers which inadvertently broke Mechanical Turk HITs that are hosted on servers which do not have SSL certificates. This happens because browsers now block unsecured iframes on HTTPS secured sites.

- [Firefox announcement of this feature being enabled by default in Firefox 23](https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/)
- [Mozilla bug report pertaining to Mechanical Turk](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=892810)
- [Chrome answer about this issue](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1342714?hl=en)

The only way to fix this is to buy an SSL certificate or bypass it in the browser. I should also let you know that [workers are aware of this issue and will know how to do your HIT anyway.](http://mturkforum.com/showthread.php?10046-problem-with-hits)

Comment: Thank you frb! I'm on a tight schedule and I'm new to web development so this problem had me in quite the panic. Awesome answer with great links!

Comment: Would a shared SSL certificate work or do people have to purchase Custom certificates?